# Is the texture normal calculated from the color of each texel of a texture?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the normal mapping, the texture used also has the texture normal in addition to the texture color, just like the following fragment shader code:

```
#version 420 core
out vec4 color;
// Color and normal maps
layout ( binding = 0) uniform sampler2D tex_color;
layout ( binding = 1) uniform sampler2D tex_normal;
```

But what I don't understand is that what type of image has that 'texture normal'?
I also searched some solutions used to calculate the texture normal with it's RGB color:

```
Red maps from (0-255) to X (-1.0 - 1.0)
Green maps from (0-255) to Y (-1.0 - 1.0)
Blue maps from (0-255) to Z (0.0 - 1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal map is usually an image in its own right—it’s not something embedded in another image. As the description you found suggests, the normal at a given point is determined from the RGB values of the normal-map image at that point. Here’s an example, from the [Wikipedia article on normal mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping):

[image: normal map example]

The shader code you posted is expecting two separate textures, the first one being the color of the material, the second one being its normal map.

Comment: Does it means that any texture could be used for retriving the texture normals to get an acceptable simulating result? Which also means that the texture normals can be randomly calculated?

Comment: Not really—in general, normal maps have to be specially created. There are tools you can use that will try to create a normal map based on a texture, but they’re kind of guessing the normals based on the lighting in the image. As to random noise… you can perturb an existing normal map with a little bit of RGB noise, but the more you add the less sense your lighting will make.

Comment: @a_shuang: These days the usual approach on creating a normal map is modelling a 3D model at *very high* resolution, then reduce the 3D model's resolution and from the difference between the models' resolution layers the normal map is generated. Here's a tutorial for doing this in Blender explaining each step http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/baking-normal-maps-from-models.php